# I'm trying to remove backslash from string but if I print out with print I get the correct string , but if I print it with "po" I get the same string

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

```
MyString = "CfegoAsZEM/sP\u{10}\u{10}}"
MyString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
```

with print(MyString)  I got this : `"CfegoAsZEM/sP"` (that's what I need)
with po MyString (on the debugger) : `"CfegoAsZEM/sP\u{10}\u{10}}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string doesn't contain literal backslash characters.  Rather, the `\u{}` sequence is an escaped sequence that introduces a Unicode character. This is why you can't remove it using `replacingOccurrences`.

In this case, as Vadian pointed out it is the "new line" character (0x10). Since this is an invisible "white space" character you don't see it when you `print` the string, but you do see it when you use `po`. The debugger shows you escape sequences for non-printable characters.  You will also see the sequence if you `print(MyString.debugDescription)`

Unfortunately the `trimmingCharactersIn` function doesn't appear to consider Unicode sequences.

We can use the `filter` function to examine each character in the string.  If the character is ASCII and has a value greater than 31 ( 32 is the space character, the first "printable" character in the ASCII sequence) we can include it. We also need to ensure that values that aren't ASCII are included so as not to strip printable Unicode characters (e.g. emoji or non-Latin characters).

```
let MyString = "CfegoAsZEM/sP\u{10}\u{13}$}\u{1F600}".filter { $0.asciiValue ?? 32 > 31 }
print(MyString.debugDescription)
print(MyString)
```

**Output**

> "CfegoAsZEM/sP}"
>
> CfegoAsZEM/sP}

`asciiValue` returns an optional, which is `nil` if the character isn't plain ASCII. I have used a nil-coalescing operator to return 32 in this case so that the character isn't filtered.

I modified the initial string to include some printable Unicode to demonstrate that it isn't stripped by the filter.

Comment: Yes you are right it works for me, thank you

Answer (score 2):

`\u{10}` is a linefeed character

Maybe a better way is to `trim` the string, it removes all whitespace and newline characters from the beginning and the end of the string

```
let myString = "CfegoAsZEM/sP\u{10}\u{10}"
let trimmedString = myString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but still only work with print()

Comment: Also I tried with this and i got the same result 
extension String {
    var unescaped: String {
            let entities = ["\0", "\t", "\n", "\r", "\"", "\'", "\\"]
            var current = self
            for entity in entities {
                let descriptionCharacters = entity.debugDescription.dropFirst().dropLast()
                let description = String(descriptionCharacters)
                current = current.replacingOccurrences(of: description, with: entity)
            }
            return current
        }
}

Comment: It's hard to judge a string containing Unicode tokens (`\u{something}`) because the appearance can be different in different environments. Consider that a linefeed character puts the cursor to a new line and it could be that new line characters are ignored when being printed.

Comment: I guess you are right, but have you an idea how  to remove it ?